# How to populate a table with 5 million rows in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on an app that should find 26-letter code in char(26) column out of 5,760,000 rows. I need to know how long it's going to take. I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 Express.

I have a database which has only one table, `myTable`:

```
Idcolumn integer  
CodeColumn char(26)  
DateAndTimeColumn datetime
```

- Column 'CodeColumn' has an index.
- IdColumn is simply integer ID.
- CodeColumn has "00592098715648275649283746" format (this is an example).
- DateAndTimeColumn is a timestamp.

I would like to populate this table with data to do some tests and to find out how long it is going to take to get an answer from the database. I don't know how to write proper tsql statement to populate my table with 5,760,000 rows. Especially that second column is very long. How can I populate the table to get my table populated?

Let's say the data should be like this when I use statement

```
SELECT IdColumn, CodeColumn, DateAndTimeColumn FROM myTable;
```

Output:

```
1   00000000000000000000000001  2014-11-19 15:46:50.843
2   00000000000000000000000002  2014-11-19 15:46:54.310
3   00000000000000000000000003  2014-11-19 15:46:56.060
```

and so on ... till 5,760,000 rows.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you generating this data or does it exist somewhere?

Comment: You need to write a TSQL block and write an insert statement in a loop. From my knowledge, I don't think you can do this in a single query.

Comment: Have you tried out a data generating product like http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/ ?

Comment: Why did you choose to place an index on CodeColumn and not on IdColumn?

Comment: @mordack550 because op said that s/he wants to search for a code in that table?, why *wouldn't* s/he add an index on that column?. "I'm working on an app that should find 26-letter code in char(26) column"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (5760000) 
              IdColumn = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT  IdColumn,
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',26)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),IdColumn),26) CodeColumn,
        GETDATE() DateAndTimeColumn 
FROM Numbers;
```

Comment: sys.all_objects only include objects in current database. If OP only got 1 table in the databse you probably need at least one more cross join to ensure you reach 5760000 rows.

Comment: yeah, I used 3 cross joins, but if it's not enough then op should add more.

Comment: I have ran the statement and it started to do "something" for over 4 hours but it didn't do nothing. My tempdb table grew up to over 50 GB and the HDD space has eventually ran out so I had to cancel it. After this I wanted to check if this statement puts anything to my target table (myTable) and I have modified it slightly by typing 10 insted of 5760000. I don't understand this query so I don't know how to manipulate it to get the job done. Is there a simple way to modify your query to put let's say 100 rows to my table ? How can I do that ?

Comment: @DearDeer Changing `SELECT TOP (5760000)` to `SELECT TOP (100)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this using Lamak's excellent example. The only difference is this will create a 10 million row cte with zero reads. When you use sys.all_objects it can get extremely slow because of all the I/O.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), 
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), 
    E6(N) AS (SELECT 1 from E4 a, E2 b, E1 c),
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E6
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT  IdColumn,
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',26)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),IdColumn),26) CodeColumn,
        GETDATE() DateAndTimeColumn 
FROM cteTally
where cteTally.N <= 5760000
```

Comment: On an aside note, [here is a thorough](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) analysis by @AaronBertrand on how to create a sequence in SQL Server. It compares the sys.all_objects approach and also the one used here (the stacked CTEs).

Comment: I have read that before but is a good refresher. The stacked cte is definitely faster once you pass the 1 million mark. Of course at 5.7M performance is not going to be stellar no matter how you slice it.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Lamak answer, this will not depends on your database structure:

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION
    SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION
    SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION
    SELECT 10
),
Joins AS
(
    SELECT TOP (5760000) 
              IdColumn = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[id]))
    FROM Numbers AS s1 --10
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s2 --100
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s3 --1.000
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s4 --10.000
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s5 --100.000
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s6 --1.000.000
    CROSS JOIN Numbers AS s7 --10.000.000
)

INSERT INTO #YourTable
SELECT  IdColumn,
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',26)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),IdColumn),26) CodeColumn,
        GETDATE() DateAndTimeColumn 
FROM Joins;
```

It just generate a list of numbers from 1 to 10 and then it crossjoins all the way to 10^7.